# What's the difference between instantiating in the field and instantiating in the constructor?

Tags: java

What's the difference between doing this:

```
public class SomeClass {
    SomeObject obj = new SomeObject();
    //rest of the code
}
```

and this

```
public class SomeClass {
    SomeObject obj;
    public SomeClass(){
       obj = new SomeObject();
    }
    //rest of the code
}
```

Comment: copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568722/on-the-thread-safety-of-instance-variable-initialization

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the chapter [12.5 Creation of New Class Instances](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#44670) of the Java Language Specification:

> Just before a reference to the newly
>   created object is returned as the
>   result, the indicated constructor is
>   processed to initialize the new object
>   using the following procedure:
>
> 1. Assign the arguments for the constructor to newly created parameter
>      variables for this constructor
>      invocation.
> 2. If this constructor begins with an explicit constructor invocation of
>      another constructor in the same class
>      (using this), then evaluate the
>      arguments and process that constructor
>      invocation recursively using these
>      same five steps. If that constructor
>      invocation completes abruptly, then
>      this procedure completes abruptly for
>      the same reason; otherwise, continue
>      with step 5.
> 3. This constructor does not begin with an explicit constructor
>      invocation of another constructor in
>      the same class (using this). If this
>      constructor is for a class other than
>      Object, then this constructor will
>      begin with an explicit or implicit
>      invocation of a superclass constructor
>      (using super). Evaluate the arguments
>      and process that superclass
>      constructor invocation recursively
>      using these same five steps. If that
>      constructor invocation completes
>      abruptly, then this procedure
>      completes abruptly for the same
>      reason. Otherwise, continue with step
> 4. Execute the instance initializers and instance variable initializers for
>      this class, assigning the values of
>      instance variable initializers to the
>      corresponding instance variables, in
>      the left-to-right order in which they
>      appear textually in the source code
>      for the class. If execution of any of
>      these initializers results in an
>      exception, then no further
>      initializers are processed and this
>      procedure completes abruptly with that
>      same exception. Otherwise, continue
>      with step 5. (In some early
>      implementations, the compiler
>      incorrectly omitted the code to
>      initialize a field if the field
>      initializer expression was a constant
>      expression whose value was equal to
>      the default initialization value for
>      its type.)
> 5. Execute the rest of the body of this constructor. If that execution
>      completes abruptly, then this
>      procedure completes abruptly for the
>      same reason. Otherwise, this procedure
>      completes normally.

So the difference is just the step (step 4. or step 5.) but the result is the same.

Answer (score 2):

The only difference is in at [which step](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) the reference is initialized. The final effect is the same.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a matter of style, it compiles to the same code.

Personally I tend to put all initialization of instances in constructors, because that works uniformly for all cases.

Answer (score 0):

In the first instance, `obj` will be initialized before the constructor is run.  This is an important nuance when you have subclasses.  The ordering of constructors and initialization blocks will be:

1. superclass initializers
2. superclass constructor
3. subclass initializers
4. subclass constructor

Comment: That's not my interpretation of the §12.5 of the JLS and I don't think it's true.

Comment: It's wrong. javac generates the code in the constructor *after* a call to the super constructor. I understand C# is different (but you can't use `this` in such expressions).

Answer (score 0):

One aspect not yet mentioned:

```
public class SomeClass {
    SomeObject obj = new SomeObject();
    //rest of the code
}
```

will initialize obj to a fixed value. But when initializing in a constructor, you can have the initialization depend on the constructor's parameters, or (with multiple constructors) use entirely different initialization expressions, e.g.

```
public class SomeClass {
    private SomeObject obj;
    public SomeClass(int length){
       obj = new SomeObject(3 * length + 7);
    }
    //rest of the code
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Time of construction. The first is done before main is entered. The other object's construction is delayed until SomeClass's ctor is called.

Comment: my bad... :( The first example would create SomeObject just before the constructor is run... Correct?

Comment: The answer is just as @Pascal copied from the JLS see #4 and #5.