# how to achieve the threadsafe without using the synchronization method or block?

Tags: java, multithreading

Can an body explain alternate way to achieve the threadsafe without using the synchronization at method level block level?

```
public synchronized int disp()
 {

  }



 or
 public int  disp()
 {
  Synchronized
   {}
  }
```

Comment: Read up on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science).

Comment: If there is no state then you don't need `synchronization`. There are various ways. `Volatile`, `ThreadLocal`, delegate to Synchronized collections etc which one to choose depends on the situation.

Comment: It depends a lot on the actual code that you have.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330941/thread-safe-code-without-using-the-synchronized-keyword

Answer (score 2):

You could just use a single thread, of course.

You can design your application to avoid sharing mutable state, so that methods are inherently threadsafe.

You can use synchronized library collections.

You can use threadsafe queues to communicate between threads (Concurrent Queues).

It rather depends on what you are trying to achieve...

Answer (score 0):

There is another variant called `Class Level Synchronization`. But it is a kind of Block level synchronization only.

But, before that can you explain in your question why is such requirement?

Comment: accoding to my view there is no class level synchronization.what is the alternative way to achieve the thread safe of the object

Comment: if you could explain why do you need another way, it will be helpful. is it for learning or are you stuck in some real time problem?