# difference between class level instantiation vs method instantiation

Tags: java, class, variables

what is difference between following variable usages

```
public class A{

    B b= new B();

    public void doSomething()
    {
        b.callme();
    }
}
```

VS

```
public class A { 
    B b;
    public void doSomething() {
        b=new B(); 
        b.callme();
    }
}
```

if we have single "b"  inside a class then which one is better practice and why.
and under what circumstances one whould be used.

Comment: @SuKu: Um, yes you can. It's an instance variable initializer. It's absolutely fine.

Comment: Did you mean the second form to be `b = new B();`? You don't have a variable called `B`...

Comment: @JonSkeet  yes.  b=new B();  ... aplogise for typo

Comment: may be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065939/difference-between-initialization-at-declaration-and-initialization-in-construct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These actually have very different meanings. In case 1, the `b` object is assigned when `A` is constructed. It is constructed once and only once (unless you are reassigning it from somewhere outside the class).

In case 2, you are reassigning `A's` instance of `b` every time the method is invoked

Comment: when we say object is intialized once then that is with respect to the classloader(am i correct)?

Comment: I should have said "assigned" (the post is now edited). By assigned, I mean it now references a `new B()`

Answer (score 0):

`Class level instantiation` will instantiate your class variables when new object of your class is created. While `method instantiation` will instantiate your variables when the method is invoked.

**Good Practice :** You should do `Class level instantiation` or `instantiate in Constructor` when your class variable is/must be `final` or else use `method instantiation` i.e `lazy initialization`

Answer (score 0):

`Case 2:` Is helpful for [lazy initialization](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=34)

`In case 1` the object of `B` is created when you create object of `A`. But if creating `B` is **heavy operation** then you can lazily create it when you actually need B instance.

`Lazy Initialization` is helpful when the creating the object is a heavy task and you want to lazily create the object instance only when it is actually being used. But do take care of `thread safety` if your class is being shared between threads.

**UPDATE**: But in your case you are reassigning the reference b everytime the method is called. Which is not Lazy initialization per se.

```
//example of lazy initialization
public B getB()
{
  if (something =  = null)
    b = new B();
  return b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first case is called inline initialization. It will happen before the body of any constructors run but after the call to the super constructor.

In the second case b is not initialized until doSomething is called().

As for which is better, that depends on your program logic. If you want a new instance every time doSomething is called, the second way is better. If you'd prefer to lazy load b then modify it to be

```
if (b == null) b = new B(); 
return b;
```

Personally I generally allocate instance variables in the constructor for the sake of readability.

```
public class A {
  B b;

  public A() {
    b = new B();
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The REAL difference here is that do you want a different instance of `B` each time `doSomething` is called? In the second case this is true but it also means that your class is not thread-safe if there are any other methods using `B`. And if there are NOT any other methods in the class using `B` why not make it a method-scoped variable?

Answer (score 0):

I was just trying out a similar scenario, but due to a mistake I created a scenario for recursion instead (StackOverflow error):-

```
public class Test{

Test t=new Test();
public static void main(String[] args) {
       Test t=new Test();
       System.out.println("Hello");
}
}
```

I think it might be helpful to some for the conceptual purpose.